# Vuejs Property or method is not defined on the instance but referenced during render

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm new in VueJS and I am trying to create a custom form component.

I am using http://element.eleme.io elements. So I created a new Form.vue file

```
<template>
    <el-form :model="data">
        <slot></slot>
    </el-form>
</template>

<script>
  import { FormItem, Input } from 'element-ui';
  export default {
    name: 'general-form',
    components: {
        FormItem,
        Input
    },
    props: ['data'],
    mounted: function() {
        console.log(this.data);
    }
  }

</script>
```

Here is my app.js

```
// Element.io
import { Form, FormItem, Input } from 'element-ui';
import 'element-ui/lib/theme-chalk/index.css';

// Custom
import GeneralForm from '../../components/presentational-subsystem/form/Form.vue';

Vue.use(Form);
Vue.use(FormItem);
Vue.use(Input);

Vue.config.devtools = true;

var contactsPage = new Vue({
  el: '#contacts-page',
  components:  {
    GeneralForm
  }
});
```

And here is my view:

```
<div id="contacts-page">

<general-form id="contacts-form" :data="{subject: 'abc'}" action="/contacts" method="post">
  <el-form-item label="Subject" prop="subject">
    <el-input v-model="data.subject"></el-input>
  </el-form-item>       
</general-form>

</div>
```

But I get this error in the console:

[Vue warn]: Property or method "formData" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.

I know that if I change Vue object to this:

```
var contactsPage = new Vue({
  el: '#contacts-page',
  data: { formData: {} }
  components:  {
    GeneralForm
  }
});
```

the error disappears, but then form is not reactive any more. I tried to follow this example:

http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/form

and my markup is actually the same, but when I use Vue dev tools, I can see that my formData variable inside my Form.vue component is different from the shared formData variable in my Vue instance.

My question would be how can I make `<el>` elements use formData from my Form component that I created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a `slot`, its scope -- where its data comes from -- is the parent. The contents of your slot refer to `formData`, which you define in the child. You can pass child data to slots using [scoped slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Scoped-Slots)

Alternatively, you could fully define `formData` in the parent and pass it as a `prop` to the child, which passes it on as a prop to `el-form`.

This structure:

```
<el-form :model="formData">
    <slot></slot>
</el-form>
```

has you passing `formData` from your `Form` component *to the `el-form` component*. It does not pass to the slot. Slots are not children, they are injected code from the parent.

The parent code:

```
<general-form id="contacts-form" action="/contacts" method="post">
  <el-form-item label="Subject" prop="subject">
    <el-input v-model="formData.subject"></el-input>
  </el-form-item>       
</general-form>
```

is creating an instance of your `Form` component and injecting an `el-form-item` as slot content. The error you are getting is in referring to `formData` in that slot content, because the slot's context is the parent. A slot does not know anything about what it's being injected into (unless you use scoped slots).

**In the updated code:**

```
<general-form id="contacts-form" :data="{subject: 'abc'}" action="/contacts" method="post">
  <el-form-item label="Subject" prop="subject">
    <el-input v-model="data.subject"></el-input>
  </el-form-item>       
</general-form>
```

You are passing a `data` prop to the `Form` child here, but trying to use it in the slot content. the `el-input` is looking in the parent for `data`. Try this:

```
var contactsPage = new Vue({
  el: '#contacts-page',
  data: {
    data: { subject: 'abc' }
  },
  components:  {
    GeneralForm
  }
});
```

and

```
<general-form id="contacts-form" :data="data" action="/contacts" method="post">
  <el-form-item label="Subject" prop="subject">
    <el-input v-model="data.subject"></el-input>
  </el-form-item>       
</general-form>
```

Comment: I failed to fully understand your comment. So if I have
<template>
 <el-form ref="form" :model="formData">
  <slot></slot>
 </el-form>
</template>

in my Form.vue, doesnt that mean that I passed my formData to my child as a prop?

Comment: Can you take a look at the updated question? I updated the code. I used your offered alternative approach, I sent Object as a prop to Form.vue from HTML file and passed it to el-form with prop too. But I still get the same error message, what I did wrong?

Comment: It works now, but I want also to ask whether it is possible to hide form data in actual Form component? I also would like to know if I am using this approach, can I edit at runtime data object? cause It is passed as prop, so I guess I can not edit it anymore.

Comment: Have the child [communicate with the parent](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Composing-Components) to update the prop. I know you're new to Vue, and there are a lot of fundamentals to learn. This is a big one.